# Understanding X.509 certificate and the makecert.exe command

Tags: ssl-certificate, x509certificate, makecert

I've used the makecert.exe to create a certificate, but I'm not sure what exactly is happening, or what some of the commands mean.

This is my command:

```
makecert -r -pe -n "CN=Test certificate" -b 10/22/2015 -e 10/22/2016 -ss my -len 2048
```

*To make things clear, I followed a guide in creating this certificate, and I simply wish to know what's going on*

I understand most of this command such as

```
-r = making the certificate self-signed, 
-pe = making the private key exportable,
-n = specifies the name of the certificate subject,
-b = specifies the beginning date of the validation period,
-e = specifies the end date of the validation period,
-len = specifies the key length in bits.
```

What I don't understand is the `-ss my`. I'm not quite sure what exactly this means. Could anyone clarify this for me?

***Note:*** if any of the other commands are wrong, please enlighten me

Comment: Please, be aware that makecert is deprecated tool in Windows: http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2012/08/14/rsa-key-blocking-is-here.aspx

Comment: @CryptoGuy Appreciate the comment!

Comment: I'm not ignorant, I just want to point that you should not bother with old and unsupported tool, instead, consider to utilize new tools. In your case -- move to certreq, or to PowerShell.

Comment: @CryptoGuy I wasn't being sarcastic. I DO appreciate the heads up :)